# Can less wrap lines like fmt does?

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu, less

Like most people I use `less` as my terminal pager.  Occasionally I view files consisting of very long lines of plain or marked-up text.  By default `less` *folds* these lines at the terminal window edge.  That is, words get broken at the last column, making the text difficult to read.  Is there any way of getting `less` to instead *wrap* the lines at word boundaries, the same way that `fmt` or Emacs visual line mode does?

I am aware that I could simply pipe the input through `fmt` before viewing it, though that requires me to know my terminal width in advance.  I was hoping there was some way of getting `less` to nicely wrap lines, and to automatically reformat them when the terminal window is resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** To verify, download the [latest `less` source](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html) and review `input.c` around line 178:

```
177             /*
178              * The char won't fit in the line; the line
179              * is too long to print in the screen width.
180              * End the line here.
181              */
182             if (chopline || hshift > 0)
183             {
184                 do
185                 {
186                     if (ABORT_SIGS())
187                     {
188                         null_line();
189                         return (NULL_POSITION);
190                     }
191                     c = ch_forw_get();
192                 } while (c != '\n' && c != EOI);
193                 new_pos = ch_tell();
194                 endline = TRUE;
195                 quit_if_one_screen = FALSE;
196             } else
```

Formatting in the way that `fmt` does is non-trivial, performance-wise. The `fmt` algorithm is about [50 lines of forward and backward scanning](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/fmt.c#n843) to get the optimal layout. Also, the `fmt` algorithm looks (IMO) wonky if the width you want is significantly larger than the actual contents, so it might not be a good general fit.

`man` uses `less -is` by default which IMO is pretty good, but not what you want.

So... I think the only way, though admittedly it doesn't follow terminal resizes, is:

```
fmt -w $(tput cols) | less
```

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the [less man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

```
-S or --chop-long-lines
    Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped rather than folded.
    That is, the portion of a long line that does not fit in the screen width
    is not shown. The default is to fold long lines; that is, display the
    remainder on the next line.
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer my question.  I want lines to be wrapped at word boundaries, _not_ chopped or folded.

Answer (score -1):

The best option that I have found for this is to use fmt to format the text and pipe it into less.

```
fmt file_name | less
```

That will achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: In the question, Psychonaut says that he knows that this is an option. If you're saying that this is the only way you know how to do it, that's not really a useful answer. You say "The best option that I have found for this is ...." You could make your answer more valuable if you described at least one _other_ option.